# Is it possible to install Linux Ubuntu using windows troubleshooting cmd?

Tags: ubuntu, windows

I once installed a newer version of windows using the cmd in Windows troubleshooting without using drivers or any softwares, I just ran the `setup.exe` file in the cmd, and the setup was successful, I am trying to convert to Ubuntu, can I do a similar thing to install Ubuntu or do I have to use a software or a driver?

Clarifying further more:

I downloaded windows.iso file I extracted it using winrar, then I typed in the search bar (I used windows 8 at the time) `change advanced start up options` and I clicked then I pressed Advanced Startup, A menu appeared, I navigated to the cmd, by pressing Troubleshoot then Advanced options, using Cmd I navigated to the folder where I extracted the windows.iso then I typed:

`setup.exe`, and the setup started running normally, I didn't use any external drivers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're referring to **windows PE**, which is a lightweight environment intended to support only microsoft related or compatible products. Since it has no intention to support anything else like **GNU/Linux**, **BSD** or other type of software, you cannot run the installation process from **windows PE**. Although you can create a partition for GNU/Linux from this environment, but that's all.

You mentioned the word convert, so I assume you would like to replace ms windows with Ubuntu Linux, is that correct?
If that's your main goal, then write the latest **x64 LTS** (Long Term Support) **image** (see [here](https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?version=22.04.2&architecture=amd64))
with Rufus (see [here](https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/releases/download/v4.1/rufus-4.1p.exe)) on a pendrive (8GB+) and boot it.
As it is a Live image, it is fairly simple to play around before you install it and also worth to mention it is great for troubleshooting as well (not just for GNU/Linux).
I don't think that you would be interested in dual boot either, so you don't need to worry about the installation process as it is mostly next-next-finish if you're just beginning to use GNU/Linux.
But before you're doing this, make a backup just in case.
And finally answering your other questions: No, you don't need to use additional software or driver, although if you have the newest hardware, then it can be a challenge sometimes to get the right driver.